# Undo (not revert) historic local commit?

Tags: git, github, commit, undo

How can I undo a commit that should never have been made, when 17 commits have been made afterwards?

Background: a colleague in my team worked solo for a month, and now its time to merge their branch to the master. However, one of the commits contains a single file that's far too big to upload to GitHub. They tried reverting the commit but GitHub still wants to upload the file in order to remove it again, so we can't just revert the initial faulty commit.

So how can we undo that commit as if it never happened? We have GitBash and Github Desktop.

Comment: Sounds frustrating. Has your colleague tried rebasing? (You'll prob need to drop both the original commit and the undo commit)

Answer (score 2):

You can do an **interactive rebase** to delete the one faulty commit.

Caution: you will change history by that and may introduce surprises if someone else has already pulled the branch.

```
git checkout colleagues-feature-branch
git rebase -i develop
```

Then in the textfile that opens, mark the desired commit with `drop` (instead of `pick`). Save and exit.

Comment: There's no way of others checking out the work because we can't get anything of their local repository (all pushing is blocked because we can't upload that single file). The positive side is that there won't be any conflicts on the branch because no-one else has touched it.

But thanks, that gives me an avenue to explore.

Comment: So perfect. Interactive rebase should be your way to go. Sometimes I create a backup branch before the rebase to be sure nothing gets lost.